# Exactly how strong is AT-AT armour?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, technology, vehicles

The only time we actually see an AT-AT in battle in its final form is at the Battle of Hoth. There, the only available firepower comes from turrets and snowspeeders, all of which are too weak to penetrate the walkers' armour. Anything stronger is deemed too valuable and is either being evacuated or forced to be abandoned as they're not defrosted from the earlier blizzard yet.

Excluding prototypes and Force-related stuff, just how strong is that armour? What armaments have proven capable of penetrating AT-AT armour and inflicting significant damage on its own without relying on external support to soften or disable the armour first?

Comment: Related, not dupe; [Is the AT-AT cockpit being a weak-point supported by canon?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/138426/is-the-at-at-cockpit-being-a-weak-point-supported-by-canon)

Comment: Related, partial dupe; [Why didn't the rebels on Hoth use X-Wings to fight AT-ATs?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29242/why-didnt-the-rebels-on-hoth-use-x-wings-to-fight-at-ats).

Comment: @Valorum The X-Wing one, I've known for awhile now. What I do want to know is what else can punch a hole through that armour - or is it just proton weapons?

Comment: "The only time we actually see an AT-AT in battle in its final form is at the Battle of Hoth." If that's the only instance in which the armor was truly tested, what kind of source would answer your question other than the information from the Battle of Hoth itself?

Answer (score 1):

At-At armor has been shown to posses varying degrees of susceptibility to various weapons and other means of attack.

### Canon:

- [Proton Torpedos](https://youtu.be/Y7Go4uHqLRA?t=41s) and [Proton Bombs](https://youtu.be/c7NKynaAP4A?t=1m2s)
- [Lightsabers](https://youtu.be/Y7Go4uHqLRA?t=2m10s)
- [RPS-6 rocket launchers](https://youtu.be/pqyTVreP0Xo?t=1m57s)
- [Taim & Bak MS-1 heavy blaster cannons](https://youtu.be/pqyTVreP0Xo?t=2m6s)
- [The Bendu's lightning](https://youtu.be/GIfp2To9Cvg?t=39s)
- [Mass-driver cannons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kZoNjrFEo9E)
- [Taim & Bak KX9 laser cannons](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLPJnvj7vPE)

### Legends:

- [Particle cannon turrets](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Particle_cannon_turret)
- [Intense radiation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Last_Command)

Comment: The mass driver though only vs. weak spots in the armor if I'm not wrong?  Additionally: Should also ion cannons be counted there?